# Magento 1.7 Soap API cart.order

Tags: magento-1.7

```
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [1002] Can not make operation because quote is not exists.
```

I have created a cart using cart.create,
added customer,products ,shipping method and payment method successfully,
I tried printing results of all above calls and its shows correct results.

but when i try to call cart.create i got the above fatal error.

Can anyone help me what can be the issue here.

Thanks